# Function is called too many times and retains old variable values

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, parse-platform

I currently have a table that is updated every time a user presses a button (handled using Backbone events).

Here is the event that is fired every time the button is pressed:

```
add: function(ev) {
            if($(ev.target).data("card-id")) {
                this.card_array.push($(ev.target).data("card-id"));
                current_deck.push($(ev.target).data("card-id"));
                updateCurrentDeckTable();
            } else {
                alert("Couldn't add the card. Please wait a few seconds before trying again.");
            }
            console.log(this.card_array);
            console.log(current_deck);
        }
```

updateCurrentDeckTable is defined as so:

```
function updateCurrentDeckTable() {
        console.log(current_deck);
        var content = "";
        $.each(current_deck, function(i, cardId) {
            console.log("Index: "+i+" || Card ID: "+cardId);
            var M_Card = Parse.Object.extend("Card");
            var M_CardQuery = new Parse.Query(M_Card);
            M_CardQuery.get(cardId, {
               success: function(m_card) {
                   console.log("Got "+m_card.get("cardTitle"));
                   content += "<tr>";
                   content += "<td>"+m_card.get("objectiveNumber")+"</td>";
                   content += "<td>"+m_card.get("cardTitle")+"</td>";
                   if (m_card.get("cardAffiliation") == null) {
                       content += "<td>-</td>";
                   } else {
                       content += "<td>"+m_card.get("cardAffiliation")+"</td>";
                   }
                   content += "<td><a>Details</a></td>";
                   content += "</tr>";
                   console.log("Content: "+content);
                   $('#deck-table tbody').append(content);
               },

               error: function() {
                   alert("Error.");
               }
            });
        });
    }
```

Now, the first time the user presses the button, everything works just fine. However, on the second press, more than one row is added to the table. Further, the `content` variable seems to keep it's old values. Shouldn't it reset to `""` every time the function is called?

Does anyone have any idea what's happening? If you need more information, please ask.

Comment: I think you might want to put var content = ""; directly after the success: function(m_card) {

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why oh why are you passing data using a global `current_deck` variable?

Each time you enter the `updateCurrentDeckTable` branch of your `add` method:

```
if($(ev.target).data("card-id")) {
    this.card_array.push($(ev.target).data("card-id"));
    current_deck.push($(ev.target).data("card-id"));
    updateCurrentDeckTable();
}
```

You're adding another entry to the global `current_deck` and then `updateCurrentDeckTable` iterates over that array:

```
$.each(current_deck, function(i, cardId) { ...
```

I don't see anything that clears out `current_deck` so it will just keep growing. That would explain the odd behavior you're describing.

The solution would be to stop using a global for `current_deck`, just pass it around as an argument and clean it up as needed.